Vite build results in file with a single import to actual output
I'm building a Vue web component with Vite in library mode. What I expect is my-component.js with the code of the component.
What I get is my-component.js containing import "./MyComponent-b224fa0f.js";.
My vite build config is:
    build: {
      lib: {
        entry: './src/MyComponent.js',
        name: 'my-component',
        fileName: 'my-component',
      },
      outDir: './my-component',
      emptyOutDir: false,
      copyPublicDir: false
    },

Adding the following to the config results in the build that I want (my-component.js), but this breaks the component when I use it externally: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
   rollupOptions: {
        external: ['vue'],
        output: {
          globals: {
            vue: 'Vue',
          },
        }
      }
    },

